# Why is this code producing a different value in a VM?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtual-machine

Basically I have these tif images that I need to recurse through and read pixel data to determine if a pixel in the image is of melting ice or not. This is determined via the threshold value that's set in the script. This is configured to be able to display both the years total melt value and also each month. It works fine on my own machine, but I need to run this remotely on a Linux VM. It works, but it produces a total number that is exactly 71146 greater than what it should be and what it had bee producing.

This is the snippet that does most of the processing and is ultimately causing my problems I believe.

```
for file in os.listdir(current): 
    if os.path.exists(file):
        if file.endswith(".tif"): 
            fname = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
            day = fname[4:7] 
            im = Image.open(file)
            for x in range(0,60):
                for y in range(0,109):
                    p = round(im.getpixel((x,y)), 4) 
                    if p >= threshold:
                        combined = str(x) + "-" + str(y) 
                        if combined not in coords: 
                            melt += 1
                            coords.append( combined )
            totalmelt.append( melt )
```

And then totalmelt is summed to get the yearly value:

```
total = sum(totalmelt)
```

The threshold value has been set previously as follows:

```
threshold = float(-0.0158)
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. It's been a while since I played with Python...I'm coming over from C++ right now. Thanks for any solutions you might offer!

Comment: Factor out a function to get the melt for a single image. It should make it obvious what the problem is. Locality of data makes code easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset `melt` to `0` before your inner loops:

```
melt = 0
for x in range(0,60):
    for y in range(0,109):
       ...
       melt += 1
totalmelt.append(melt)
```